# WCF OperationContract and dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, messagecontract

I have a WCF Service that based on [Writing Highly Maintainable WCF Services](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95). Requests are processed using a CommandService:

```
[WcfDispatchBehaviour]
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://somewhere.co.nz/NapaWcfService/2013/11")]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public class CommandService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public object Execute(dynamic command)
    {
        Type commandHandlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());
        dynamic commandHandler = BootStrapper.GetInstance(commandHandlerType);
        commandHandler.Handle(command);
        return command;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        var coreAssembly = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly;
        var commandTypes =
            from type in coreAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
            where type.Name.EndsWith("Command")
            select type;

        return commandTypes.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Everything works great (thanks Steve) but now I need to add the ability to upload a file to the service. From what I've read and based on errors received during testing, WCF needs to use a `[MessageContract]` when uploading a file using a `Stream`. So I've decorated my command class and put the non-Stream members into the message header, and updated my binding definition to use streaming:

```
[MessageContract]
public class AddScadaTileCommand
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream Content { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately when I call the service with a file to upload I get an error:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://somewhere.co.nz/NapaWcfService/2013/11:command. The
>   InnerException message was 'Type 'System.IO.FileStream' with data
>   contract name
>   'FileStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' is not
>   expected.

So I added a new method to the service specifically for the file upload request:

```
[OperationContract]
public void Upload(AddScadaTileCommand addScadaTileCommand)
{
    Type commandHandlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(AddScadaTileCommand));
    dynamic commandHandler = BootStrapper.GetInstance(commandHandlerType);
    commandHandler.Handle(addScadaTileCommand);
}
```

This works perfectly, unless I change the `AddScadaTileCommand` parameter to `dynamic` in the method definition, in which case I get the same error as above. This appears to indicate that the `[MessageContract]` attributes are not applied or ignored when using `dynamic` as the type of the parameter. Is there any way to resolve this or will I need to create separate methods for requests that involve streams?